# Elegant way to conserve .gitconfig separatly?

Tags: git

The reference https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config says configuration for git are conserved by three scopes, system, global and project specific.

I wonder is there any other way to separate more specific scopes between global and project.

For example, I have many project related to my official work and at that time I need user.name = "NAME IN CORP". OTOH others need user.name = "NAME IN PUBLIC".

The problem is projects which belong to two scopes that I mentioned (work, public) are too many to specify project-scope one by one. Is there any effective way to solve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "too many to specify project-scope one by one"?  Surely you can write a script to  configure all of the extant projects, and then set GIT_TEMPLATE_DIR when creating new projects.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I mean there are too many projects that I have to write .gitconfig one by one. Surely I can deal with it by writing script, but I think there is more natural way using git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since git 2.13, it is possible to solve this using newly introduced [Conditional includes](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes).

An example:

Global config ~/.gitconfig

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = john@doe.tld

[includeIf "gitdir:~/work/"]
    path = ~/work/.gitconfig
```

Work specific config ~/work/.gitconfig

```
[user]
    email = john.doe@company.tld
```

Comment: Seems to be right way that I am trying to find. Thanks.