# Git global config for specific repositories?

Tags: git

Meaning, having something like a per repo section `[repo_url]` that overrides global(not for a specific repo) options.

```
[core]
    filemode = false
    editor = notepad
[repo "example.com/repo1.git"]
    [core]
        filemode = true
        # editor = notepad
[repo "example.com/repo2.git"]
    [core]
        editor = vim
        # filemode = false
```

Is possible in git?

Note: I'm making a lot of clones(`git clone`) of repos which I would specify in such a global config

Comment: I don't *think* there is a way to do this from your global configuration file, but each repository has its own configuration file (`.git/config`). You can edit that manually, or use the `--local` flag when running `git config`.

Comment: Group repositories in directories and use conditional includes. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49154229/7976758, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018125/7976758

Comment: @phd, thank you. Didn't know about `includeIf`. That's a pretty random feature!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Git 2.36 (Q2 2022), you will have another option than relying on a local folder: the conditional inclusion mechanism of configuration files using "`[includeIf <condition>]`" learns to base its decision on the *URL* of the remote repository the repository interacts with.

See [commit 399b198](https://github.com/git/git/commit/399b198489a041e2842fb4b257bea5adb02d28d1), [commit ed69e11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed69e11b89af41c112ab80f5278a2b29c6f5f5b3) (18 Jan 2022) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 13ce8f9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13ce8f9f148637a885003c63e11a020d0aeca3f7), 09 Feb 2022)</sup>

> ### [`config`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/399b198489a041e2842fb4b257bea5adb02d28d1): include file if remote URL matches a glob
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jonathan Tan</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Elijah Newren</sup>

> This is a feature that supports config file inclusion conditional on whether the repo has a remote with a URL that matches a glob.
>
> Similar to my previous work on [remote-suggested hooks](https://lore.kernel.org/git/cover.1623881977.git.jonathantanmy@google.com/), the main motivation is to allow remote repo administrators to provide recommended configs in a way that can be consumed more easily (e.g. through a package installable by a package manager - it could, for example, contain a file to be included conditionally and a post-install script that adds the include directive to the system-wide config file).
>
> In order to do this, Git reruns the config parsing mechanism upon noticing the first URL-conditional include in order to find all remote URLs, and these remote URLs are then used to determine if that first and all subsequent includes are executed.
> Remote URLs are not allowed to be configured in any URL-conditionally-included file.

`config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/399b198489a041e2842fb4b257bea5adb02d28d1/Documentation/config.txt#L162-L188):

> ### `hasconfig:remote.*.url:`
>
> The data that follows this keyword is taken to
> be a pattern with standard globbing wildcards and two
> additional ones, `**/` and `/**`, that can match multiple
> components.
> The first time this keyword is seen, the rest of
> the config files will be scanned for remote URLs (without
> applying any values).
> If there exists at least one remote URL
> that matches this pattern, the include condition is met.
>
> Files included by this option (directly or indirectly) are not allowed
> to contain remote URLs.
>
> Note that unlike other `includeIf` conditions, resolving this condition
> relies on information that is not yet known at the point of reading the
> condition.
>
> A typical use case is this option being present as a
> system-level or global-level config, and the remote URL being in a
> local-level config; hence the need to scan ahead when resolving this
> condition.
>
> In order to avoid the chicken-and-egg problem in which
> potentially-included files can affect whether such files are potentially
> included, Git breaks the cycle by prohibiting these files from affecting
> the resolution of these conditions (thus, prohibiting them from
> declaring remote URLs).
>
> As for the naming of this keyword, it is for forwards compatibility with
> a naming scheme that supports more variable-based include conditions,
> but currently Git only supports the exact keyword described above.

`config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/399b198489a041e2842fb4b257bea5adb02d28d1/Documentation/config.txt#L256-L263):

> ```
> ; include only if a remote with the given URL exists (note
> ; that such a URL may be provided later in a file or in a
> ; file read after this file is read, as seen in this example)
> [includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:https://example.com/**"]
> path = foo.inc
> [remote "origin"]
> url = https://example.com/git
> ```

Comment: For SSH connection you need to use ssh protocol:
`git remote set-url origin ssh://git@gitlab.com/your/repo.git`
and in your config file `[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:ssh://git@gitlab.com/**"]`

Comment: @KévinBerthommier Good point. That should work too.

Comment: @KévinBerthommier You can avoid having to edit the repo's origin by matching gitlab's default SSH URL format in your config file using `[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:git@gitlab.com:*/**"]`

Answer (score 1):

Solution: `includeIf` (big thanks to @phd)

global config

```
[core]
  filemode = false
  editor = notepad
[includeIf "gitdir/i:repo1/"]
  path = path_to_repo1_git_config  
[includeIf "gitdir/i:repo2/"]
  path = path_to_repo2_git_config
```

repo1_git_config

```
[core]
  filemode = true
```

repo2_git_config

```
[core]
  editor = vim
```

That way any repository to which repo1/repo2 is a parent(not immediate) directory will have respective config included. Note the slash at the end of each `includeIf ([read docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_conditional_includes)).

Answer (score 0):

local and conditional configs will work for your title question, but there's no condition based on what's in a repo's remote urls. Considering local clones that idea immediately starts looking fragile and confusing.

It might make more sense to have a condition based on whether or not a particular commit exists in a repository, but there's no indication in your question what the motive is here. If you'll explain what situation you're in that prompts this question, it might get more helpful answers.

Comment: The apparent confusion between "repo" and (I had to guess) origin url makes the question far from clear, I chose to address the apparent desire for url-based configs in my answer, for which the answer is ~you can't do that, it would't be a good idea, but you can get close as comments have said~. Which is a pretty good paraphrase of the answer given.  So I disagree.